# How to pass an argument to Plink in VBA

Tags: vba, batch-file, outlook, putty, plink

I am trying the following string in command prompt to execute some (test) remote commands on my server:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw [PASSWD] [U/NAME]@[SERVER] -m cmds.bat -v
```

In my `cmds.bat` file I have some test commands:

```
sleep 3
@echo off
ls -la ~/
@echo on
sleep 1
```

I now want to beef this up to run a remote script while passing an argument. The argument will be handled and appended by my VBA code. This is the part I am stuck at. Please note the following VBA code is only a snippet; the part that calls Plink. The surrounding code, I am happy with:

```
If re.Test(Msg.Subject) Then
    Set matchCol = re.Execute(Msg.Subject)
    For Each match In matchCol
        shellStr = "plink.exe -ssh [USERNAME]@[SERVER] -pw [P/WORD] -m cmds.bat " & match
        Shell(shellStr, vbNormalFocus)
    Next
End If
```

The offending line is:

`shellStr = "plink.exe -ssh [USERNAME]@[SERVER] -pw [P/WORD] -m cmds.bat " & match`

I do not know how to append the value held in variable `match` (captured by the Regexp) to the string to be executed in opening the shell.

The bat file will handle the command for actually running the script on the remote Unix server, where instead of `ls -la ~/` in the above example I will use:

`python ~/myscript.py [ARGUMENT FROM VBA VARIABLE "match"]`

But how do I pass this `match` variable's value into this?

Comment: I'm now thinking that writing a bat file on the fly from VBA with `match` value appended to the command to run the script on the remote server from VBA dynamically before calling the shell is the way forward.

Comment: What data type is `match`? What is its value? What error do you get? What value would you like `shellStr` to have?

Comment: `match` is a string. It will be like "ABC123" I've adapted my code to write the `cmds.bat` file on the fly. I don't see how else to pass this to plink to be executed on the remote side.

Comment: It might be easiest for you to use something like `sendKeys`.

Comment: Again, what error do you get? You say what the "offending line" is, but in what way is it offending you? At this point you haven't made clear what your problem is exactly...

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this; plink just doesn't support this usage. your best bet is doing what you suggested in your comment: build the script on the fly. (and maybe don't call it .bat, that seems misleading a bit …)